# SOAP and REST webservice in single application

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, soap, spring-boot

Is it possible to develop both SOAP and REST webservice in single application using spring boot or spring mvc. I have been looking for some example but not able to find.

For Example: myWebAddress is my application

1. Passing XML request through SOAPUI to my application by hitting SOAP URL(http://ww.mywebaddress.com/soap)
2. Passing request as parameter to same application by hitting REST URL(http://ww.mywebaddress.com/soap?parameter)

If possible, could you provide some simple example or link to any example.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use SOAP Webservices and Spring MVC together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139533/can-i-use-soap-webservices-and-spring-mvc-together)

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Hi, Its not the thread which you have mentioned. I'd like to have both SOAP and REST webservices in single application.

Comment: which is http://stackoverflow.com/a/17140220/643500 SoapUI will take the WSDL URL for SOAP

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can create two web service types for the same Spring web application, but you have to be careful with namespaces.

For SOAP, you will publish a WSDL and use an end point.  The WSDL will be consumed and a client web service call will be generated on the calling side.

Check this [example for soap](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

For RESTFUL, you will create a `@RestController` with a `@RequestMapping`.

Check this [example for rest](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Also, read:

[Can I use SOAP Webservices and Spring MVC together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139533/can-i-use-soap-webservices-and-spring-mvc-together)

[Both REST and SOAP Web Services for a single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414615/both-rest-and-soap-web-services-for-a-single-application)

[Can I use Spring MVC and Spring WS in one single application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078795/can-i-use-spring-mvc-and-spring-ws-in-one-single-application)

Comment: Thank you So much. Let me try.